# Cannot add object as hash value in Rake: TypeError: no implicit conversion of DropboxClient into String

Tags: ruby, rake, dropbox-api

I use the following code for my DropBox in a Rake task:

```
require 'dropbox_sdk'

ENV['DROPBOX_APP_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'access key'
ENV['DROPBOX_APP_KEY'] = 'key'
ENV['DROPBOX_APP_SECRET'] = 'secret'

flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.new(ENV['DROPBOX_APP_KEY'], ENV['DROPBOX_APP_SECRET'])
client = DropboxClient.new(ENV['DROPBOX_APP_ACCESS_KEY'])
```

This part is just how you connect.  It's from the API documentation and works fine.

What's weird though is when I try to store the `client` object into the ENV hash I get:

```
ENV['DROPBOX_APP_CONNECTION'] = client
TypeError: no implicit conversion of DropboxClient into String
```

If I do the same thing in IRB, it works fine.  Even if I create a different Hash instead of ENV, it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same error in `irb`, and it makes sense to me.

[`ENV`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ENV.html) is for getting and setting environment variables, which have string values. So you can't store something that's not a string in it.

I'm not sure why you're trying to do that anyway? Are you trying to pass the client off to some other process? If so, I'd suggest just having the other process create its own client using the access token you've already stored in `ENV`.

Comment: First I'm just trying things out and second ENV just seems like a great place to store those variables.  I didn't know ENV was not just a Hash object.  That's pretty interesting... I wonder why.  Do you have any article about that by any chance?

Comment: I linked to the documentation for ENV in my answer.